# R: stats package functions such as rnorm() and runif() do not work

Tags: r

After updating R, I found that some functions like `rnorm()` and `runif()` were not working. Functions don't work not only in my code, but even the simplest examples like `rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 2)`. R writes that can't find the function "rnorm". Everything else works. What does this mean? These are standard functions of the Stats package, I can't install or reinstall it. What could be the problem?

When loading, R gives a message about the problem:
"Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
can't load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
LoadLibrary failure: The specified module was not found."

I use the latest version of Windows 10, my current version of R is 4.0.2. I installed R 4.0.3, but the problem remained

Comment: Is `stats` on your search list?  Run `search()` (or for more information, `sessionInfo()`) to see.

Comment: It's not in the search list

Comment: `library(stats)` will add it back.  Normally `stats` is attached by default, but you can override that in various ways -- see `?Startup`.

Comment: `library(stats)` doesn't work. Returns an error: "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module was not found."

Comment: Although R gives an error that there is no library, but if follow the specified path, the library is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was not with R, but with RStudio. I installed a fresh version of R, but the problem remained. This was already suspicious. The error that was displayed in the R Studio console indicated a problem with a specific library, but it was still not R itself, but with RStudio. I decided to check what would happen if I ran the same command in pure R. The command worked normally, so everything was fine with R itself and its libraries. I deleted the temporary files of RStudio and after that everything started running normally in it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you, but deleting temporary RStudio files did not fix it for me. I found that my PATH variable was incorrect, and when I updated it my base packages were working again. The `Sys.getenv("PATH")` function will tell you where your current PATH variable is set to, which should be wherever you have installed R. For whatever reason, my PATH was set to `C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin` but, for me, should be `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\bin\x64`. I updated the PATH with `Sys.setenv(PATH="C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/bin/x64")` and that fixed it for me.